# any subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Any subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is _______
>
> 1. cyclic and  finitely generated but not abelian and normal,
> 2. cyclic and  abelian but not finitely generated  and normal,
> 3. abelian and normal but not cyclic and  finitely generated, or
> 4. finitely generated and normal but not cyclic and abelian.

I know

1. that any finitely generated subgroup of ($\mathbb{Q},+)$ is cyclic and hence abelian and hence normal,
2. $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is cyclic, abelian, generated by $\{1,-1\}$ and of course normal.

But I am not able to figure out or tackle the above statements separately.

Comment: None of those are true. Every subgroup of $\bf Q$ will be abelian and normal, which rules out #1. As a bonus, there are also noncyclic, non-finitely generated subgroups of $\bf Q$, e.g. ${\bf Z}[1/2]$, ruling out #1, #2 and #4. There are cyclic (hence finitely generated) subgroups of $\bf Q$ (multiples of $\bf Z$ by a rational basically), which rules out #2 and #3 and #4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a very strangely worded question, but I *think* it's probably meant to be a fill-in the blank multiple choice question which would more intelligibly be stated as:

> Every subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**.
>
> A) cyclic and finitely generated, but not necessarily abelian or normal.
>
> B) cyclic and abelian, but not necessarily finitely-generated or normal.
>
> C) abelian and normal, but not necessarily cyclic or finitely-generated.
>
> D) finitely generated and normal, but not necessarily cyclic or abelian.

Since $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is an abelian group, every subgroup is obviously abelian and normal, which rules out A, B, and D, so the answer is C.  Of course you want to actually be able to put your hands on a non-finitely generated subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$, so as anon says in the comments, consider the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$, i.e. the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ consisting of elements where the denominator is a power of 2.

(Note that a finitely-generated subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ has an upper bound on its denominators, and is in fact cyclic.)

Comment: can you please elaborate how you discarded option 3?

Comment: I didn't, that's the answer.